# How to find before VAT and total vat amount from the total bill amount?

Tags: javascript

In this case,
total bill amount 210
(vat percentage : 5%)

**before vat: 200
vat amount: 10**

How to find this before VAT and VAT amount from the total bill amount.I want to show these two in different fields.

Comment: this is not a coding issue. This is a simple math problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let total = 210;
let vatPercetage = 5;

let vat  = (vatPercetage * total) / (100 + vatPercetage)
billBeforeVat = total - vat
```